# Append "<li><a hef='#'>text</a></li>" to "<ul>" using jQuery foreach & append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

I am trying to create a list of links dynamically using the results from a call to a web service. I have the `<ul>` element in my HTML.

```
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

And I am trying to use jQuery foreach and append to create the list items.

Given the following data:

```
var options = {
    {href: "#", text:"text"},
    {href: "#", text:"text"},
    {href: "#", text:"text"},
    {href: "#", text:"text"}
};
```

I thought I could create the list using the following script:

```
$each(options, function(index) {
    $("#myList").append($("<li>", {}).append($("<a>", { href: options[index].href })).text(options[index].text));
});
```

Although it is kind of working, the text is ending up outside of the anchor elements. What I want to end up with is:

```
<ul id="myList">
  <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: I dont understand....that output looks fine....show us the wrong output ;)

Comment: You have 1 too many closing brackets before `.text(`

Comment: Robert: the output I provided was the desired, not the result. The result was <li><a href="#"></a>Text</li>; as pointed out by some of the answers, I was setting the text on the <li> instead of the <a>.

Comment: Jamiec: probably another typo; it seems I made quite a few when typing this question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be nesting the `append`s incorrectly. Try:

```
$.each(options, function(index) {
    $("#myList").append(
        $("<li>", {}).append(
            $("<a>", { href: options[index].href }).text(
                options[index].text
            )
        )
    );
});
```

The way you had it, you were adding the `text` to the `<li>` and not the `<a>`.

Comment: Once you changed the layout like that it became obvious. Thanks very much, though there are many right answers I am marking yours as the one I accept because your layout change reminded me how I might avoid a similar situation in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You were close, but your syntax is slightly wrong.

```
var options = [
    {href: "#", text:"text"},
    {href: "#", text:"text"},
    {href: "#", text:"text"},
    {href: "#", text:"text"}
];

$.each(options, function(index) {
    $("#myList").append($("<li>", {}).append($("<a>", { href: options[index].href }).text(options[index].text)));
});
```

You need an array of options which contain your objects. You also had a syntax error on `$.each`. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5ZDZX/1/

Comment: Please see my comment to Jeff Shaver; I recreated parts of the example on the fly and in doing so got a few typos! Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$.each(options, function(index) {
    $("#myList").append($("<li>").append($("<a>", { href: options[index].href , text : options[index].text})));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uMUzf/

Comment: Ahh; never thought of setting "text" as an attribute. Did not realise that would be valid. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're setting the `.text` of the `li` **not** the `a` tag.

Also, your `option` object is set up incorrectly using `{ }` instead of `[ ]`

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/4WTG3/**

Try this:

```
var options = [
    {href: "#", text:"text"},
    {href: "#", text:"text"},
    {href: "#", text:"text"},
    {href: "#", text:"text"}
];

$.each(options, function(index) {
    $("#myList")
    .append($("<li>", {})
        .append($("<a>", { href: options[index].href }).text(options[index].text)
    ));
});
```

Comment: Yes, you got my point exactly - I just could not see why. Like the answer from Steve, your layout makes it much clearer. Thanks.

Comment: @MartinRobins No problems glad I could help! Yeah I always structure nested `append` calls like that, otherwise it's incredibly hard to see what you're referring to!

Answer (score 0):

You need array of objects and your append statement seems a bit overly complicated:

http://jsfiddle.net/x23ja/

You also needed to use `$.each` instead of `$each`

Comment: Sorry; my bad, I was trying to create a simple example rather than having to post actual code. You are right though; in doing that I managed to create a non-array of options and I missed the "." from the jQuery call.

Answer (score 0):

I used this succesfully

```
$.each(result, function (i, file) {
                $("#filelist").append('<li><a target="_blank" href="' + downloadUrl + '/' + file.StaticFileId + '">' + file.ShortDesc + '</a></li>');
});
```